# Verify in which activity is a fragment attached

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a way to verify in which activity is a fragment attached ?

I tried something like:

```
if (getActivity().equals(MainActivity.class))
```

but with no result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use instanceof

```
if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity.class)
```